# Blender problems with getting the center of an object. (Origin to center is not the center)

Tags: transforms, error, object-mode, origin, transform-orientation

As you will see in this image, the center of the object is not exactly the center of the chair, since the pivot point is slightly up.

[image: blender no center object]

To verify this, I place the cursor in the center of the world and use a cube to check if it is offset up or down.

[image: blender no center object with pencil marks]

How can I really center an object? Since apparently blender does not calculate the position well or there is something I do not understand

Answer (score 3):

The origin of an object can be anywhere you like with respect to the object's mesh.

There are two possible definitions of 'center' provided by Blender's *Header menu > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry* operation, in Object Mode.

- 'Median Center', which is the mean location of the object's vertices
- 'Bounds Center', which is the center of the object's bounding
  box.

It looks as if you want 'Bounds Center'.

(In Edit mode, the behaviour of <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> *Cursor to Selected* also varies, depending to whether 'Median' or 'Bounding Box' is selected as Transform Pivot Point.)

Comment: Learned something new here, thanks :).

Comment: From the tests I did, the center of origin is not in the center of the object ... that's the problem.
Try with the 2 shapes you say and there is no case, it is never in the center, always higher or lower ... It seems to me that there is an error in the internal calculation of Blender3D.

Comment: I've never had this as a problem ... say... Cursor to selected, with Bounding Box Pivot  set (and axes orthogonal to mesh)... and then Origin to 3D Cursor? Could you share your file on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ?